# What classical conditions give unique Laplace equation solutions on a half-plane?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

Solutions of the Laplace equation on the upper half plane of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ are not unique:
$$
                    \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}u+\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}u = 0,\;\;\; -\infty < x < \infty,\;\; y > 0,\\
                      u(x,0) = g(x)
$$
What types of classical conditions on $g$ and $u$ guarantee unique solutions? I'm interested in any and all types of common, classical conditions that people have seen.

Comment: $u(x, y) \rightarrow 0$ as $y\rightarrow \infty$ would be one.